# Facebook instant Article and icon images

Tags: html, facebook-instant-articles

I have a problem with icon images in the body text that I don't want expand to full width. This is in the rss-feed I output.
I tried using:

```
<figure data-mode="non-interactive"> <img 
src="https://example.com/path/to/img.jpg" width="70" height="70" /> 
</figure>
```

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/image)

But that didn't do much. The only thing that kinda works is if I put the image in an iframe:

```
<figure class="op-interactive">
<iframe class="column-width" src="http://example.com/path/to/img.jpg" width="70" height="70"></iframe>
</figure>
```

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/embeds)

But then I can't use align on the picture. Should be a way to use small images in an instant article